# new column in pandas DataFrame based on unique values (lists) of an existing column

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a dataframe where some cells contain lists of multiple values. How can I create new columns based on unique values of those lists? Those lists can contain values already included in previous observations, and also can be empty. How I create a new column (One Hot Encoding) based on those values?

CHECK EDIT - Data is within quotation marks:

```
 data = {'tokens': ['["Spain", "Germany", "England", "Japan"]',
 '["Spain", "Germany"]',
 '["Morocco"]',
 '[]',
 '["Japan"]',
 '[]']} 
my_new_pd = pd.DataFrame(data)

0    ["Spain", "Germany", "England", "Japan"]
1                        ["Spain", "Germany"]
2                                 ["Morocco"]
3                                          []
4                               ["Japan", ""]
5                                          []
Name: tokens, dtype: object
```

I want something like

```
   tokens_Spain|tokens_Germany |tokens_England |tokens_Japan|tokens_Morocco 
0        1              1              1              1           0
1        1              1              0              0           0 
2        0              0              0              0           1
3.       0              0              0              0           0
4.       0              0              1              1           0
5.       0              0              0              0           0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method one from `sklearn`, since you already have the list type column in your dfs

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
yourdf=pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['tokens']),columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index)
```

Method two we do `explode` first then find the dummies

```
df['tokens'].explode().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0).add_prefix('tokens_')
   tokens_A  tokens_B  tokens_C  tokens_D  tokens_Z
0         1         1         1         1         0
1         1         1         0         0         0
2         0         0         0         0         1
3         0         0         0         0         0
4         0         0         0         1         1
5         0         0         0         0         0
```

Method three kind of like "explode" on the axis = 0

```
pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(df.tokens.tolist()),prefix='tokens',prefix_sep='_').sum(level=0,axis=1)
   tokens_A  tokens_D  tokens_Z  tokens_B  tokens_C
0         1         1         0         1         1
1         1         0         0         1         0
2         0         0         1         0         0
3         0         0         0         0         0
4         0         1         1         0         0
5         0         0         0         0         0
```

---

Update

```
df['tokens'].explode().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0).add_prefix('tokens_')
   tokens_England  tokens_Germany  tokens_Japan  tokens_Morocco  tokens_Spain
0               1               1             1               0             1
1               0               1             0               0             1
2               0               0             0               1             0
3               0               0             0               0             0
4               1               0             1               0             0
5               0               0             0               0             0
```

Comment: impressive 3 strategies! I think the most intuitive is the explode and get_dummies.

Comment: it works with single caracters as values of the lists but does not work with strings! check now how can I make it with strings instead. Thanks ! :D @YOBEN_S

Comment: @Javiss still work on my side , check the sample output

Comment: @YOBEN_S sorry mate, I got the data in another format (with quotation marks), then your solution does not work on my data :(

Comment: @Javiss `import ast ; df.tokens=df.tokens.apply(ast.literal_eval)`, then all above will work